# Why not trap stack writes above ebp to avoid overflow exploits?

Tags: c, assembly

I've been looking at StackGuard and similar, and also Intel's new technology preview on "Control flow enforcement" (basically a shadow stack), here: https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/4d/2a/control-flow-enforcement-technology-preview.pdf.

Obviously there is a reason why what I'm wondering will either break everything or not protect against buffer overflows, but its simple so I'm sure someone can explain why I'm barking up the wrong tree.

[image]

Why not implement in CPU hardware an optional feature to abort/trap when writing to a stack address higher than or equal to ebp?  This would protect the return address and function parameters from being overwritten via a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use of `ebp` as frame pointer is optional, but of course that could be changed. Worse problem is that you may legally write outside of your stack frame, such as if you got a pointer to a variable belonging to a caller:

```
int foo;
scanf("%d", &foo);
```

Obviously `&foo` points outside of the frame of `scanf`.

Function parameters don't need to be protected, they can be legally modified too. This could also be changed, however.

Comment: Yeah after days trying to figure it out, I ask stackexchange, go have a shower and realise the same thing as your answer in the shower and come back and I'm too late... Doh.